# Wrapping each child key within an UL

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm wanting to wrap each child array within an `<ul>`, but I'm not entirely sure how it may be done?

```
function RecursiveWrite($array) {
    foreach ($array as $v) {

        echo '<li>';

            echo $v['id'];

            if(isset($v['children']))
                RecursiveWrite($v['children']);

        echo '</li>';

    }
}

echo '<ul>';
RecursiveWrite($comments);
echo '</ul>';
```

Outputs:

```
    <ul>
        <li>81
            <li>173</li>
            <li>84
                <li>85
                    <li>131
                        <li>176</li>
                    </li>
                </li>
                <li>174</li>
                <li>175</li>
            </li>
        </li>
        <li>178</li>
    </ul>
```

The output I'm wanting to get:

```
<ul>
    <li>81
        <ul>
            <li>173</li>
            <li>84
                <ul>
                    <li>85
                        <ul>
                            <li>131
                                <ul>
                                    <li>176</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>174</li>
                    <li>175</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>178</li>
</ul>
```

Original array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '81',
    'parent' => NULL,
    'children' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => '173',
        'parent' => '81',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => '84',
        'parent' => '81',
        'children' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => '85',
            'parent' => '84',
            'children' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'id' => '131',
                'parent' => '85',
                'children' => 
                array (
                  0 => 
                  array (
                    'id' => '176',
                    'parent' => '131',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'id' => '174',
            'parent' => '84',
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'id' => '175',
            'parent' => '84',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '178',
    'parent' => NULL,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Can't you just echo `<ul>` before **and** after the array loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to echo out the `<ul>` tags before and after your foreach loop.

Simple as...

```
function RecursiveWrite($array) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        ...
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

RecursiveWrite($comments);
```

Comment: @Chaplin no need to feel stupid :) even if your question was indeed simple, you actually **showed some effort** and that alone makes you better than at least 60% of the questions asked these days. Keep up the good work and see you around ;)